# SSH Connect to Existing Gvim Window

Tags: ssh, remote, gvim, x-windows

From what I understand, gvim is an X-window application, so it's possible to start the application remotely and be connected to the window via SSH. Is it possible to connect to an existing gvim window when you ssh into a machine running the gvim process?

I am trying to connect to my gvim session on an Ubuntu machine from my OSX laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect to an existing X11 display with plain `ssh`. To move the window to a different X11 display, you will have to use [xpra](http://xpra.org/). (gVim must be started *inside* xpra for it to work.)

Ubuntu:

```
xpra start :100
DISPLAY=:100 gvim
```

Mac (if it has `xpra` installed too):

```
xpra attach ssh:ubuntubox:100
```

Mac (if it doesn't have `xpra`):

```
ssh -Y ubuntubox "xpra attach :100"
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the 1st and 2nd option (i.e. having xpra or not on the mac)?

Comment: Possibly. #2 uses raw X11 over SSH, which is somewhat slow. #1 is supposed to use xpra's optimized protocol over SSH.

Comment: #2 is an order of magnitude slower, bordering on unusable - don't bother, mac builds are available

Comment: btw, in recent versions, you can do it all in one command: "xpra start ssh:HOST:DISPLAY --start-child=gvim"